# Regarding interaction between dynamic routing and local Bundle in a NextJS application

Tags: next.js

A newbie question about how pages are resolved in a NextJS application.

(a) Are dynamically routed pages rendered on server side only ? Or can they be rendered on client side as well ?

(b) Are dynamically routed pages bundled and sent to the client, to avoid a round trip to the server ? Or does a reference to a dynamic page will hit the server all the time (ignoring any caching).

(c) To clarify what is in my mind with regard to question (b), even though a page is dynamically routed, it can be bundled and sent to the client and during interactions the dynamic page can be looked up in the local bundle. So, trying to understaning how it works under the hood.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read through the docs of next.js, which should answer these kind of questions.

(a) In general, pages can be rendered on the server or the client, however, there are some cases in which serverside rendering is not possible/suitable.

(b) This depends on the page the user tries to access. Some HTML is generated on each request (Server-side rendering), some HTML can be generated when building the app (Static generation).

(c) I am not sure if I understand this question in the correct way but I will try to answer it.
When requesting a pre-rendered Page from the server, there is a process called [hydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/#:%7E:text=Hydration%20is%20the%20process%20of,time%20into%20a%20React%20application.) (you should look this one up). This allows a prerendered page to update data by component instead of fetching a new page.

You should also have a look at Next.js 13 which introduces [server components](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components).